# Inconsistent Behavior for Touch Events on PhoneGap

Tags: android, jquery, knockout.js, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3

I searched for weeks for a slide plugin that would work on a Phonegap app using knockout, bootstrap and jQuery. Unfortunately, nothing was fitting my needs. So, I built a custom slider. It seems to be working (I'm currently testing it on Android 2.3.4 - I'm starting with the lowest version we plan to support), but it doesn't always respond. The touchstart event seems to be rather sensitive. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make the user experience more consistent and reactive to the touchstart event? I have researched on this for a few days, and it seems others have similar issues, but nothing exactly like mine. And none of the issues seem to have a definitive answer. Does Phonegap have issues with touch events?

Here is my knockout function:

```
 performSlide: function() {
       $('#sliderDiv').on({ 'touchstart' : function() {
        $('div.slideArrow').animate({
        left: "+=200"
            }, 1000, function() {
                shell.navigate('home', 'slide');
            });
             }
    });
    }
```

I'm using the event binder on a div to call the function.

```
<div class="linkHeader" id="sliderDiv" data-bind="event: { touchstart: performSlide }">
```

I have also ensured that the z-index of my div is set higher than the other elements. The position attribute is also set to relative.

Any advice offered would be much appreciated. I would love if this performed a little better... ok, a lot better. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not received an answer, but I ended up figuring out what I needed to change. First, I needed to detect my event and capture it in a variable. Then, I also changed the databinding and .on function to detect the touchmove instead of the touchstart. It is working much better now.